# Skobbler: centerMapOnCurrentPosition() centers me in Aftrica even though blue dot is correct

Tags: android, skmaps

I am using the skobbler sdk for maps.
I use this code to center map view on current position, but even though the blue dot is at my correct current position in Los Angeles (I verify by manually going there), the map centers me at gps(0,0).

```
public void onCurrentPositionUpdate(SKPosition currentPosition) {
        this.currentPosition = currentPosition;
        mapView.reportNewGPSPosition(this.currentPosition);

        if(firstPositionUpdate){
            firstPositionUpdate = false;

            mapView.centerMapOnCurrentPosition();

        }
}
```

and heres my code for initializing the map:

```
private void initializeMapView() {
    currentPositionProvider = new SKCurrentPositionProvider(getActivity());
    currentPositionProvider.setCurrentPositionListener(this);
    if (DemoUtils.hasGpsModule(getActivity()) && ((LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)).isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        currentPositionProvider.requestLocationUpdates(true, true, true);
    }

    SKMapViewHolder mapViewGroup = (SKMapViewHolder) getView().findViewById(R.id.map_surface_holder);
    mapView = mapViewGroup.getMapSurfaceView();
    mapView.setMapSurfaceListener(this);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setFollowerMode(SKMapSettings.SKMapFollowerMode.NONE);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setMapRotationEnabled(true);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setMapZoomingEnabled(true);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setMapPanningEnabled(true);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setZoomWithAnchorEnabled(true);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setInertiaRotatingEnabled(true);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setInertiaZoomingEnabled(true);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setInertiaPanningEnabled(true);
    SKVersioningManager.getInstance().setMapUpdateListener(this);

    mapView.centerMapOnPosition(new SKCoordinate( -118.123,34.123));
    //launchRouteCalculation();
}
```

Comment: So, after mapView.centerMapOnPosition(new SKCoordinate( -118.123,34.123)); you are translated to (0,0)  ( west of Africa) ?

Comment: no, once onCurrentPositionUpdate gets called, I get translated to 0,0. before I added centerMapOnCurrentPosition(), I would get centered a the hard coded coordinates set in the init function.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that reportNewGPSPosition(this.currentPosition); does not work instantly.

I noticed that if I simply delay the call to  centerMapOnCurrentPosition(), the map is centered correctly. There are two work arounds:

-set location manually:

```
mapView.centerMapOnPosition(new SKCoordinate( currentPosition.getLongitude(), currentPosition.getLatitude()));
```

-or create a delayed runnable to call to perform the centering at a future time:

```
android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mapView.centerMapOnCurrentPosition();
                mapView.setZoom(10);
            }
        },100);
```

note: This issue only becomes evident because of the if statement I put in to only center the map on the first update of location. Another work around would be to put a use a counter and center map on the second time the location is updated.

Also if implementing this with the mentioned if statement, don't forget to consider accuracy; it would be bad to center when the location is not accurate, and not center on a future location update which IS accurate.